# Onclick function don't work with muut

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hey i made a simple onclick function.
First i added this to a webpage

```
 <a class="muut" href="https://muut.com/i/gnitterde/comments:<?php echo LANG2; ?><?php echo $feedHash; ?>"><div class="muut-spacer" id="comment"> <?php echo CMS_24; ?></div></a>
```

Were the Echo is the translation

on the end of my page i added

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("#comment").click(function(){
  $.getScript("<?php echo CMS_57; ?>"); return false;
});
    </script>
```

Were the CMS_57 is the javascript source. So if I click now on the link it will load the js (200 ok) but nothing happens. The Comment script will not show up. A bit curios..

**Edit from reporter**: Here the pure javascript code, picked up from the comments section

```
<script type="text/rocketscript">
  $("#comment").click(function()
  {
     $.getScript("https://cdn‌​.muut.com/1/moot.de.min.js");
     return false;
  });
</script>
```

and the html code:

```
<a class="muut" href="https://muut.com/i/gnitterde/comments:de6995c8b6cb469cc0932b80e0fc0bdcde"> 
  <div id="comment" class="muut-spacer">Kommentieren</div>
</a>
```

Comment: And how looks the pure html source code (what the browser has received)?

Comment: it recieves `<script type="text/rocketscript">$("#comment").click(function(){$.getScript("https://cdn.muut.com/1/moot.de.min.js");return false;});</script>` and  `<a class="muut" href="https://muut.com/i/gnitterde/comments:de6995c8b6cb469cc0932b80e0fc0bdcde">
<div id="comment" class="muut-spacer"> Kommentieren</div>
</a>`

Comment: I put your code into your post, so you can delete your comment.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 possible problems:

1) You need to wrap your code into `$(document).ready(function() { ... your code here ... });`
This allows the js code to be executed when the dom is completely loaded.

2) verify that you don't have an error in the js console of your browser

Comment: Thanks for the hint, i wrote     `<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#comment").click(function(){
          $.getScript("<?php echo CMS_57; ?>"); return false;
            });
        });
    </script>` Sadly the same result, there is no error message in the console, he loads the js but nothing happens. (200 OK
  316m)

Comment: Here is the whole pastebin code to the browser http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=juMReaVS